# Ember UI not loading

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Ember UI is not loading on staging env with below error message in the console

```
vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:2693 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at De (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:2693)
    at n.property (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:2709)
    at Le (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:2727)
    at vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:4507
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at s.callback (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:4507)
    at s.exports (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:18)
    at s._reify (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:21)
    at s.reify (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:20)
    at s.exports (vendor-fc7ff223306b879e26e5fb5c6862cc79.js:17)
```

I am clueless what could cause this and it not reproducible locally.
As it is working fine locally.

But when I open the UI in staging it gives me a blank page and above error message in the console.

Comment: How are you building the application for staging environment? Are you using a `yarn.lock` or `npm-package.lock` to ensure that the same version of dependencies are used for staging build as you are using locally? Is a build for staging environment working locally or is only the development environment working fine locally?

Comment: I am using package.lock file. and build using `ember build -prod`

Comment: It was working fine we have to redeploy the code post that it started failing there was no code changes.

Comment: Is a local build using `ember build --prod` working fine or showing the same issue? Do you have a source map to see at which part of the app it's breaking?

Comment: how do I test or run `ember build --prod` generated ui?

Comment: `ember serve` supports an `--environment` flag, which allows you to specify the build environment: `ember serve --environment production`. It also supports the `-prod` alias as `ember build` does.